# 2 different selections that link to one page

Tags: php, html

I have a problem to get 2 values from 2 selection that links to a new page that read database based on the the selected options.

if i select Year 4 and 2015, the next page after clicking VIEW button should be a table with 4 attributes (name, id, mark and grade) which located in student table.

how to solve this?

part of html :

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php choose_first_class(); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label>Year of Study</label>
         <select class="form-control" name="option1">
             <option>Choose one</option>
             <option value="4">Year 4</option>
             <option value="5">Year 5</option>
             <option value="6">Year 6</option>
         </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
         <label>Year of Class</label>
         <select class="form-control" name="option2">
              <option>Choose one</option>
              <option value="2015">2015</option>
              <option value="2016">2016</option>
              <option value="2017">2017</option>
         </select>
    </div>

<center><button type="submit" name="choose" class="btn btn-primary">View</button></center>

</form>
```

part of function :

```
function choose_first_class(){

if(isset($_POST['choose'])){

    if ('option1' == "4" && 'option2' == "2015"){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_year = 'T4'' AND study_year = '2015' AND group = 'FIRST' ";

    redirect("a.php");
    }

    else if ('option1' == "4" && 'option2' == "2016"){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_year = 'T4' AND study_year = '2015' AND group = 'FIRST' ";

   redirect("b.php");
    }else if ('option1' == "4" && 'option2' == "2017"){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_year = 'T4' AND study_year = '2015' AND group = 'FIRST' ";

    redirect("c.php");
    }else if ('option1' == "5" && 'option2' == "2015"){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_year = 'T4' AND study_year = '2015' AND group = 'FIRST' ";

   redirect("d.php");
    }else if ('option1' == "5" && 'option2' == "2016"){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_year = 'T4' AND study_year = '2015' AND group = 'FIRST' ";

    redirect("e.php");
    }else if ('option1' == "5" && 'option2' == "2017"){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_year = 'T4' AND study_year = '2015' AND group = 'FIRST' ";

    redirect("f.php");
    }else if ('option1' == "6" && 'option2' == "2015"){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_year = 'T4' AND study_year = '2015' AND group  = 'FIRST' ";

    redirect("g.php");
    }else if ('option1' == "6" && 'option2' == "2016"){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_year = 'T4' AND study_year = '2015' AND group = 'FIRST' ";

    redirect("h.php");
    }else if ('option1' == "6" && 'option2' == "2017"){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_year = 'T4' AND study_year = '2015' AND group = 'FIRST' ";

    redirect("i.php");
    }

    else
       echo "try again";
}
```

}

Comment: `'option1' == "4" && 'option2' == "2015"` you are comparing two strings. this will not work.

Comment: `if ($_POST['option1'] == "4" && $_POST['option2']== "2015") ` ?

Comment: wow...thanks you... it works.. but is there other way that i can use? because here is just 2 options. how about 3 or more options? it should be too long if i use this style. and i prefer php.